# warning:threshold violation:number of warnings exceeded threshold

Tags: swift, xcode, carthage

[image]

When I am building Xcode 9.2 project, this error is getting. Can anyone help me on this.Thanks!

Comment: resolve your problem with other warnirngs...

Comment: that looks like a swiftlint error, do you have a swiftlint build phase?

Comment: yes, I have. I am using 0.16.1 version which was working earlier. today I am getting this error

Comment: you can run `swiftlint` from the terminal from the project folder, you can also use `swiftlint autocorrect` which can fix some basic issues for you. otherwise, just correct the warnings you get when running swiftlint and then it should pass

Answer (score 4):

`Shell Script Invocation Error` referring the swift-lint errors here, which is due to the exceeding the maximum number of allowed warnings by swiftlint.

Either you have to resolve the warning, or you can increase the **number of allowed warnings by swiftlint** in swiftlint.yml by:

**warning_threshold: 2000**

For more reference you can visit [visit-medium-blog](https://medium.com/cocoaacademymag/swiftlint-introduction-tutorial-cd692d41dda3)